# Firebase updates documents fields while expected to not do that (using transactions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

For my website I store notifications per user in a `UserDocument`.
Each UserDocument has a collection named `notifications`.
In this collection there are multiple `NotificationDocuments`.

```
users/<uid>/notifications/<notification_id>

NotificationDocument:
message: str
is_read: bool
generated_id: str
```

A notifcation could be: "You have 2 replies on your comment X"

When another reply is posted on the users' comment, the SAME NotificationDocument is updated to become:

"You have 3 replies on your comment X".

Now, the NotifcationDocument has a is_read status. By default `is_read=False`.
However, when a user reads a notification, this NotifcationDocument is set to `is_read=True.

Then there is the race condition.
What if a user wants to mark it's notification as read, but in the meanwhile another notification enters, updating the content to "You have 4 replies on your comment X".
If the NotificationDocument has changed within the time that the user wants to mark it as `is_read=True` I want to skip the update.

So, I thought, let's use Firebase transactions:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions

This is the code I have for marking a NotificationDocument as read:

```
    def mark_notification_as_read(
        self, notification_id: str, expected_generated_id: str, uid: str
    ) -> None:
        """
        Mark a notification with given `notification_id` as read, but only if it hasn't been updated in the meanwhile.
        This is done by checking if `generated_id` is still the same.
        """
        path =  f"users/{uid}/notifications"
        transaction = self.client.transaction()
        notification_ref = self.client.collection(path).document(notification_id)

        @firestore.transactional
        def update_in_transaction(transaction, notification_ref):
            snapshot = notification_ref.get(transaction=transaction)
            time.sleep(10)
            found_generated_id = snapshot.get('generated_id')

            if found_generated_id == expected_generated_id:
                transaction.update(notification_ref, {
                    'is_read': True,
                })
            else:
                # Log for now, to be able to monitor if this is handled well
                logger.info(msg="Can't mark notification as read as it has been updated!")

        update_in_transaction(transaction, notification_ref)
```

Note that within the time.sleep(10), I update the `generated_id` to a new value in the firebase console. I expect that this transaction should then fail.
However, after those 10 seconds are passed, I see that the notification is marked as is_read=True anyways.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So after some more testing, I found that Firebase prevents updating a field when that field has been updated in the meanwhile.

However, it doesn't prevent updating a field that has not been updated in the meanwhile but one of the other fields has been updated in the meanwhile.

Comment: This seems that your transaction failed, because of the situation where you might modify your the value from two threads, one in the transaction of the new message and the other in the transaction originated by reading a message. This Should be giving an error message can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I solved my specific problem by not using transactions, but by using a `write_option`.

Basically, I receive the snapshot's `update_time` (a field given by Firebase), and when I do the update, I pass this on as a write_option. Stating: if on update the last_update is not the same, then fail the `update` action.

```
    from google.api_core.exceptions import FailedPrecondition

    [...]
        path = f"users/{uid}/notifications"
        notification_ref = self.client.collection(path).document(id)
        snapshot = notification_ref.get()

        if snapshot.exists:
            if snapshot.get("generated_id") == generated_id:
                write_option = self.client.write_option(
                    last_update_time=snapshot.update_time
                )
                try:
                    notification_ref.update({"is_read": True}, option=write_option)
                except FailedPrecondition:
                    pass
     [...]
```